# How does a UIAlertView determine the vertical and horizontal center of the view it's within?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiscrollview, uialertview

I'd like to use this same solution with my UIView to get the same result.
I have a UIView with a UIScrollView. These are embedded in a UINavigationController.

A customer adds an item to their basket and I would like to give them a confirmation message. Right now a little basket UIBarButtonItem updates a title within to show the number of items. This is fine but not every user/customer will notice this.

I don't really like the style of a UIAlertView for this situation. So I'm going to add my own UIView and style it how I want to.

I'm trying to figure out how to get the UIView to show up in the center of the window. Whether the customer is using an iPhone4 or iPhone5.

**UIView code:**

```
UIView *confirmationPopup = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 200, 300, 100)];
[confirmationPopup setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

//  confirmationPopup.center = [confirmationPopup.superview convertPoint:confirmationPopup.superview.center fromView:confirmationPopup.superview.superview];
[[[self navigationController] view] addSubview:confirmationPopup];
```

The popup view is centered horizontally automatically but not vertically. I've tried to play around with the line you can see I've commented out but it doesn't center the UIView in the center of the window. It appears to be centering it inside the NavBar

Would appreciate some solutions.

Comment: The first problem with your centering logic is that it depends on a non-existent superview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't hard-code; use auto layout. You might be helped by my [custom class for this purpose](https://github.com/mattneub/custom-alert-view-iOS7/tree/master/CustomAlertViewDemo), an imitation alert view substitute that you can configure however you like. It takes advantage of iOS 7 custom presentation view transitions. (Of course in iOS 8 there will be even more support for this kind of thing, i.e. UIPresentationController.)

Comment: Works great. Let's say I wanted to use different custom style. How do I do this? If I edit the one xib file then that new style would be used for all instances.

Comment: Right, you'd use a different class/.xib pair for every "style". This is no different than how any other presented view controller works right now. That's the whole point. It turns your presented view controller into an alert-looking thing. Just abstract away the custom transition code (i.e. bundle up all the `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` stuff into another object that you can instantiate as needed).

Comment: As I said before, in iOS 8 that abstraction will be even easier because you will be able to reuse  your UIPresentationController - in fact, in iOS 8 that's how UIAlertView _does_ work (I was ahead of my time on this one).